# old file name stuck at the top of sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext3

Very strange issue here, it's not causing problems but is aesthetically annoying. I had the kindle plugged into my windows machine as to edit the kindle's files. One of the kindle file names is now listed after the name of the python program I'm working on in sublime text. To paint a picture, above the menu drop downs in sublime text, there is the path to the document (IE python program) I'm working on, followed by the random file from the kindle.

The kindle file is no longer on my computer and never had anything to do with sublime text. I've tried restarting the computer and reinstalling sublime text, neither worked. Any ideas what might be going on??? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Would you mind attaching a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sublime text window caption shows you the name of the currently open file, followed by the name of the current project in parentheses (if you have a project open at all), followed by the name of the program.

Based on the screenshot in your image:

1. You currently have the file `softmax.py` open and it is stored in a folder on your desktop named `machine learning\python programs\test\newyorktest\`
2. The name of the Sublime project file is `Casting the Circle_A Woman's Book of Ritual_B009FKTQD8_sample.sdr.sublime-project` (the caption doesn't show the `sublime-project` part because that's redundant).

I would imagine that when you set up the project you accidentally chose that name as the name of the project file.

In order to fix your problem, select `Project > Save Project As...` from the menu and enter a different name for it. The location that you save the file in doesn't matter (it can be inside the folder of your project or in some other location), all that is important is that it has the extension `.sublime-project`.

Once you pick the new name, Sublime will immediately swap to using the new project file instead of the old one, which will keep your current set of open files, etc, and the caption will change.

You can then seek out and delete the other project file if you want.

Comment: I did Project > Remove all folders from project (because I didn't even know that was a thing...not sure how that happened)

worked great, Thank You!!!